# How can I disable the mobile theme for a single page?

Tags: bigcommerce

I recently uploaded custom html and css for one page on my big commerce store.The page is responsive, and mobile optimized. It works on desktops, but is over ridden by the generic mobile theme that is installed when I view it on my phone. How can I stop this page from being over ridden by the mobile version, without disabling the mobile theme completely?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods off the top of my head.

### First method

Any HTML file on BigCommerce, with a mobile/responsive theme, has 2 copies of some part of the HTML page.  The mobile HTML/CSS is simply triggered by an HTML class `mobile` on the HTML copy that is there to be only seen on mobile, which contains one copy of relevant HTML (ie, menus, logo, shopping cart icon and link, etc).

Another HTML block has class `desktop` and is only triggered for certain screen sizes (similar to `mobile`), and only shows it's desktop version of the HTMl when the screen size conditions are met.

So if screen is small, in your responsive.css file, `.mobile` is `display:none;`, while `desktop` class has all the proper visible CSS.

On the reverse, on desktop-sized screens, the `desktop` HTML is properly styled, while the `mobile` class HTML block is `display:none`.

So, in this first solution, you would simply place a copy of your custom HTMl and style it properly for display on mobile screens.  This way, the mobile-styled version will only show up on mobile devices, while the desktop properly-styled version will only show up on dektop size screens.  As far as BC goes, I think this is the optimal method.

---

### Second method

You can make a custom template for the page in question.  So if it's `product.html` and you want it custom for some specific product(s), you would create a `product-custom.html` and place it in your WebDav "/template/Panels" folder.

Now, on your product(s) which must use the new custom HTML, go to their page and scroll to the bottom and you will see a template file selection box, which should say `product.html`.  Change that to your new `product-custom.html`.

Now, as for the custom file, simply edit the HTML/CSS rules revolving around `.desktop` and `.mobile` class (possibly just removing them all together) so that when a page is loaded on a small screen, the CSS rule to hide the desktop version won't apply.  At the same time, you should delete the duplicate `.mobile` class HTML as it will no longer be needed.

This second method is much more flexible but also takes more work and is generally much more messy and requires much more maintenance.

I strongly recommend method #1.

Let me know if this helps and if you have nay other questions.